# How can I remove an unwanted and not exactly known contribution to a measured signal using correlation?

Tags: numpy, scipy, filtering, signal-processing, correlation

I conduct measurements in which an unwanted signal contribution is added to the wanted signal because the measurement sensor oscillates (in a non-trivial manner, with spectral power at different frequencies).
I have fixed an acceleration sensor to the measurement sensor and I know that the acceleration signal has to be strongly correlated to the unwanted signal contribution.
Can I use this information to remove the unwanted signal contribution from the observed signal without making assumptions about the shape and spectral content of the wanted signal?

To make it clearer what I want to achieve, I've written a minimal code example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

time=np.linspace(0,1,32768)

slope=3.0
intercept=10.0
mysignal=slope*time+intercept

frequency=15.0
acceleration=np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*time) #known
undesiredsignal=np.random.randn()*acceleration #some unknown transfer function between acceleration and undesiredsignal, here a simple factor, could be more complex

observedsignal=mysignal+undesiredsignal

plt.plot(time,observedsignal)
plt.show()
```

How can I now obtain **mysignal** from **observedsignal** using only knowledge about **acceleration**?

(I've looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter but if I understand it correctly, I need to know the covariance matrix of v, which in my case is the desirable part, whereas s is the part I have correlation information about and which I want to remove, so quite the opposite use case to recovering a signal with known shape.)

I'm grateful for all help,
thanks

Comment: If the "noise" is assumed to be Gaussian, then a curve fit (linear in your example) may be one way to give you `mysignal` from `observedsignal`. If your acceleration varies then you could conceivably fit a series of piecewise lines or higher order fit. I'm not sure this is strictly a programming question...

Comment: It depends on the nature of the noise.  For example, if I answer this question with the noise in your example, would you accept the answer or would you say, "that's not the nature of my noise, my new question is..."?

Comment: @EdSmith: If I knew the exact way the acceleration translates into the unwanted signal contribution, I could just calculate this contribution from the known acceleration and subtract it from the observed signal. But I don't know the exact translation function and it will depend on exact measurement conditions.

Comment: @tom10: Yes, I probably would, so I guess it's more a signal processing question than a programming question. I'm hoping it's possible to calculate the correlation between **acceleration** and **observedsignal** and from that derive a filter to remove only **undesiredsignal**. That would be the inverse of the transfer function between **acceleration** and **undesiredsignal**. I don't know how to find such a filter.

Comment: You don't need to know the acceleration (or even **undesiredsignal**) to fit a curve but once you've fitted a curve, you can test the level of noise (covariance from the fit) against the measured acceleration. If you perform a study of the **acceleration** vs **undesiredsignal** for a known/controlled **observedsignal**, you can then parametrise an equation (or train a network) to determine the level of noise you have at any given acceleration.